# Does my XP from Spec Ops: Missions carry over to Spec Ops: Survival mode?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I've noticed that I gain experience while playing Spec Ops: Survival mode, and the more XP I have, the more things I can unlock.  I was playing Spec Ops: Missions mode earlier, and I noticed an XP counter at the end of the mission.

Does this XP carry over to Survival mode?  Can I use Missions mode as an easy way to level up for Survival?

Comment: That is a good question! Nice Hat...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the experience level carries over between survival and missions.